# array searching vs nested if else in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, search, loops

What would be the array searching version of this loop? So this same loop below without the nested if else.

```
Test t;
int A;
int B;
int C;
int D;
int F;

for(int i = 0; i < gradeCount;i++){
    if(t.getScore() <= 100 && t.getScore() >= 90)
        A++;
    else if(t.getScore() >= 80 && t.getScore() <= 89)
        B++;
    else if(t.getScore() >= 70 && t.getScore() < 79)
        C++;
    else if(t.getScore() >= 60 && t.getScore() < 69)
        D++;
    else if(t.getScore() <= 59)
        F++;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to know..?

Comment: plz rephrase/rewrite your question/

Comment: @AhmedZ. rephrased above

Comment: The way your `if` statements are written, you could just save time and say `A = B = C = D = F = gradeCount`.  (e.g., all numbers will be less than 100 or less than 90, so A++ will trigger each time.  All scores will be greater than or equal to 80 or less than or equal to 89, etc).  Once written properly, though, you _will_ need a bunch of if/else statements inside your for loop.

Comment: @scottMermelstein I fixed that. But there isn't another way to write this?

Comment: You should be more concrete. BTW I think you meant `t.getScore() <= 100 && t.getScore() >= 90)` in the first condition.

Comment: Not really.  Sometimes, there's no way around an `if/else if/else if/else` kind of chain.  In this case, there won't be a cleaner way.  user871289's answer below is doing it, but is much less clear and maintainable than the code you wrote.  That answer also relies on the fact that your grades all start at a multiple of 10.  You need to use *and* (&&), not *or* (||) in your statements, though.  A 'B' is when the value is >= 80 AND <= 89.

Answer (score 0):

```
int results[5];
for(int i = 0; i < gradeCount; i++) {
   //if you are between 99 and 90
       //index will get set to 0
       //ex 9 - 95/10 = 0
   //if you are between 89 and 80
       //index will get set to 1
       //ex 9-89/10 = 1
   int index = 9 - t.getScore()/10;
   //if 100 or larger, we have to set it to 0, otherwise index would be negative
   if(index < 0) index = 0;
   //if less than 50, index will be too large and nothing is worse than F
   if(index >= 5) index = 4;
   results[index]++
}
```

The counts originally in the individual variables A,B,C,D,F and now saved into an array, "results".

where:

results[0] is A

results[1] is B

...

results[4] is F

Comment: Could you please explain this code? I did clean up the OP as well.

Comment: Cleaned it up and added comments...not a perfect solution, but im not really sure what the question is to begin with..

Answer (score 0):

This program is self-explaining. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()  {

  int rank[5]={0};

  //rank[0] is grade F
  //rank[1] is grade D
  //rank[2] is grade C
  //rank[3] is grade B
  //rank[4] is grade A

  int num=0;
  cout<< "Enter a number b/w 0-100, press -1 to exit"<<endl;

  while(num != -1)
  {
     cin>>num;
     int oneTenthOfNum = num/10;
     int index = (oneTenthOfNum<=5)? 0: oneTenthOfNum%5;
     rank[index]++; 
  }

  return 0;
}
```